# Scenes from "The Fly" that I seem to remember wrong

Tags: movie, the-fly

In the last weeks I watched two of the "The Fly" movies with a buddy. It was "The Fly" from 1986 and "Return of the Fly" from 1959. "The Fly" from 1958 and "The Fly II" we also know but haven't seen them for a long time. We both seem to remember scenes that have not been in the movies we have seen so far. I wonder if they might be from other films after all.

1.) Teleportation of a cactus (or a similar plant). This should have happened in "The Fly" from 1986 before the teleportation of the monkey. The cactus was messed up but the monkey's teleportation was successful. Therefore, it should have happened before. I have the assumption that this is actually a scene from Star Trek Next Generation. A malfunction of the replicator.

2.) Also from "The Fly" from 1986, I remember a scene that didn't seem to be in the movie. Seth Brundle often uses voice control on his computer. I remember that he later loses his ability to speak. Instead he uses a recording of his voice that Veronica Quaife made.  She actually made these recordings at the beginning of the film during an interview with Seth Brundle.

Are these scenes real or is my brain playing tricks on me?

Are they maybe from The Fly II from 1989?

Or do they belong to other movies?

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097368/trivia mentions a cactus, so the first might be a memory of The Fly 2.  I'm pretty familiar with Star Trek TNG, and can't recall any scene like you described.

Comment: @Kai I found the same trivia, which seems to match. I do not remember a voice recording in the original film either, so that could also be from the second film.

Comment: Maybe it was a different version of the movie,  like a director's cut